# Android app won't connect to computer that's connected wirelessly to network

Tags: java, android, sockets

The app uses sockets to connect to the computer but will only connect if the computer is connected to the network by an ethernet cable. I've tried disabling the firewalls but that makes no difference.

The code for the server on the computer:

```
int port = 7936;        

while(true){
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);
System.out.println("Waiting for client ...");
Socket client = server.accept();
System.out.println("Client from "+client.getInetAddress()+" connected");

InputStream in = client.getInputStream();
```

and the code for the client on the app:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(address,7936);
OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
String action = "2";
byte[] actByte = action.getBytes();
out.write(actByte);
socket.close();
```

Address is defined by user input and all the permissions needed have been set in the manifest xml file.
Thanks for the help.

Edit

Sorry for the delay in responding to the answers given. I have since been able to try the program on a different network and it works with the computer connected wirelessly so it looks like the issue was with the network rather than the code.

Thanks to everyone for answering and I'm sorry it took me so long to respond.

Comment: Have you tried disabling the Wired adaptor on the server when the wireless one is in use?

Comment: Do you get an error on the client or server?

Comment: You should provide more details: server OS, firewall status, logs as @faceman said, etc.

Comment: Using Windows? Confirm the IP address with `ipconfig` and listening services with `netstat -an | find /i "LISTENING"`. Post your results if anything is out of the ordinary.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, more information is needed.  When you disconnect the computer from the wired connection, I assume it is switching over to wifi and you've verified that you are online.  Your computer is likely to get a different IP address if you're DHCP as the interface changed and so wouldn't the MAC address.

Check the address on the computer and verify you have the right address.

Answer (score 0):

What I'm thinking is that the socket is not bound to the IP address you think it is. You may wish to try using the [TcpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx) class, that way you can bind it to the IP address (network adapter) you want.